# Android clearing recent applications list

Tags: battery-life, ram, recents-screen

After exiting the applications on my Galaxy nexus, they appear on the recent applications list. Do they still use CPU/battery? Do I have to remove them from recent applications list in order to save battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent applications list show only what applications have been recently used, it doesn't check whether they're still running or using memory/CPU. Therefore, this list doesn't affect battery use one way or the other.

Instead, you might want to check `Settings -> Apps -> [swipe to the right]` to show running applications, processes and services. Here you can see the apps that are using your device and consuming battery, and kill unnecessary processes by tapping the app and then `Stop`.

Comment: What's about cached processes? Do they still use CPU/memory? Should I end them as well?

Comment: Android does a really good job at managing its own memory; there's generally no reason for you to micromanage it. It's only in cases of a poorly-designed app or a stuck process that you even want to bother.